# Selenium driver.quit() in a different Class/method not closing when I put them in the "main"

Tags: java, selenium

I have 4 classes with methods in each. The 1st class is the "main" class where everything is put together to run. The 2nd class is where the driver is started and where this lives: public WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver(); The 3rd class is where I'm creating methods to open different webpages and finally the 4th class is where I wrote 2 methods one to quit the driver and the other to close Chrome pages.
Now my issue is that when I put the methods together everything runs with the exception of drive.quit() and drive.close(). I been searching everywhere to find the answer and tried various things. Still can't get it to close or quit. Here's my code:

```
    //  Main: 

    import QuitBrowser.QuitChrome;
    import WebPages.ChromeBrowserTest;
    
    public class AutoMain 
    {
        public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException
        {
            ChromeBrowserTest web = new ChromeBrowserTest();
            QuitChrome quitter = new QuitChrome();
            
            //opens webpage method
            web.webPage();
            Thread.sleep(1000);
           //Quits chrome driver method
            quitter.quitChrome();
            System.out.print("Execution Complete");
           }  // end main method
    
         }// end Automain class



        //Chrome Driver starter class: 
       package ChromeConnection;
       import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
       import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;

       public class ChromeConnector 

      {
        public WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
    
         public void ChromeStarter()
         {
           System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "/Users/xxxx.xxxxx/eclipse-workspace/chromedriver");
            
         }// end ChromeStarter method
    
     }// end Chrome Connector class


     // WebPages that I'm going to open class: 

     package WebPages;

     import ChromeConnection.ChromeConnector;

     public class ChromeBrowserTest 

    {
      ChromeConnector connection = new ChromeConnector();
    
      public void webPage() throws InterruptedException
       {
        try
          { connection.ChromeStarter();
        
        
            connection.driver.get("https://formy-project.herokuapp.com");
            
          }
            catch(Exception e)
          {
            System.out.print(e + " webPage ");
          }
        
          } //end webpage method
        
        }// end ChromeBrowserTest class


        // Finally the final class, where I have the quit & close methods. 
        package QuitBrowser;

        import ChromeConnection.ChromeConnector;

        public class QuitChrome 
         {
           ChromeConnector connection = new ChromeConnector();

           public void closePage() throws InterruptedException
         {
           try
           {
              connection.driver.close();
           }
              catch(Exception e)
           {
              System.out.print(" Close Window " + e);
           }
         }// end closePage method
    
         public void quitChrome() throws InterruptedException
          {
             try
             {
                 connection.driver.quit();
                
             }
             catch(Exception e)
             {
                System.out.print(e + " quitChrome method ");
             }
            
          }//end quitChrome method

         } //end quitChrome method


        // When I put the quit method and close method it just does not work. Any help is truly appreciated. Thank you!!!
```

Comment: "when I put the methods together everything runs with the exception of drive.quit() and drive.close()" -- exactly what goes wrong with those methods?

Comment: they both get ignored. the text I put in to print, prints. But the Chrome browser does not close out. Thanks.

Comment: the problem is you're creating a new "connection" in your QuitChrome class.  Declare/initialize the webdriver more globally and pass reference in to your other classes.  (in constructor or setter) How you design the architecture there will depend on your needs.

Comment: @pcalkins beat me to it.

Answer (score 1):

Thank you @pcalkins ! I see what you are saying. Make it "more globally". This is what i did:

I added "static" to public WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();

```
public class ChromeConnector 

{
    public static WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();  // here is the change

    public void ChromeStarter()
{
    System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "/Users/xxxx.xxxxx/eclipse-workspace/chromedriver");
        
}// end ChromeStarter method
```

}// end Chrome Connector class

Then I was able to call the WebDriver in a different class like so:

```
    public void quitChrome() throws InterruptedException
     {
        try
        {
            ChromeConnection.ChromeConnector.driver.quit(); //here is the change I had to call the package ChromeConnection, then the class ChromeConnector, then drive.quit();
            
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            System.out.print(e + " quitChrome method ");
        }
        
       }//end quitChrome method
```

Thanks!